# AzureML Experiment doesnt finish (Complete) - outputs exists

Tags: python, azure, gzip, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a pythion script which I run as:

```
config = ScriptRunConfig(
    source_directory='logic', 
    script='sense/myscript.py',
    arguments = ['--val', 'decode'],
    compute_target=target,
    environment=myenv_local,
)
# submit script to AML
run = exp.submit(config)
```

The script which I run has these steps at the end of script:

```
print('---- Fitting pipeline')
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)

print('Saving joblibs')
    
dill.dump(pipeline, gzip.open('./outputs/baseModel_LR_MONTH0_5D.gz',"wb"))
print('---- Finished.')
```

The output in azureml looks like this:

```
---- Fitting pipeline
Saving joblibs
```

But it never prints the "**---- Finished.**" and shows that the job is running:
[image]

The model I save to output is there in the run and I can download it:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was it was still processing. Thee job lib being produced was about 27GB that's why it looked like it was stuck but actually, it was writing files.